# Since when black box is called "black box"?

Tags: flight-data-recorder

In addition to [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/2723/3230). Is there any noted moment of time when "black box" name was first time used for calling actually orange-painted FDRs? Was there any other name ("orange box"?) before?

Or is it that they have been called "black boxes" ever since actual introduction to aircrafts?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because maybe it belongs to http://history.stackexchange.com

Comment: Voting to reopen. Certain users here seems to be missing "since when" part or seems to be getting it equal to "why", which is an obvious mistake. I want to know since when black boxes are called black boxes (i.e. is there any recorded moment in aviation history when black boxes were not called black boxes?)? Such information is not provided in linked question and thus marking this question as duplicate is a misunderstanding as per me.

Comment: There are answers to the linked question that do address the "since when" part as well.

Comment: @fooot Judgement depends on how you understand "exact duplicate" meaning. My question, by no mean, is an exact duplicate. Following your way of thinking, asking question "Which newspaper or dictionary first time noted usage of 'black box' meaning" would also count as an exact duplicate of that question. I think, you see my point. There are literary dozens of things addressed "as well" in linked question. But, that is not the way how we should understand "an exact duplicate" meaning here, right?